# Show that, given the space of Riemann integrable functions, $f \mapsto \sqrt{\int_K f^2}$ satisfies the triangle inequality

Tags: compactness, riemann-integration

The gist of this is that, given $f, g \in J$, where J contains all Riemann integrable functions on a compact rectangle, then $\sqrt{\int_K (f+g)^2}\leq \sqrt{\int_Kf^2} + \sqrt{\int_K g^2}$.

Now, I tried removing the radicals, resulting in ${\int_K (f+g)^2}\leq {\int_Kf^2} + {\int_K g^2} + 2{\int_Kf^2} {\int_K g^2} \iff {\int_K f^2+\int_K g^2 +2\int_K fg}\leq {\int_Kf^2} + {\int_K g^2} + 2\sqrt{\int_Kf^2} \sqrt{\int_K g^2}$.

I want to think there's a way to show that $\int_K fg\leq \sqrt{\int_Kf^2} \sqrt{\int_K g^2}$ in order to end the proof, but I can't think of any.

I'm barely beginning to understand compact sets and integration in compact sets, so any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Try it first with the analogue for functions on a _finite_ set, to see that it doesn't have much to do with integration, really. :)

Comment: thanks a bunch! Right after I posted the question I found out about the CBS inequality, and I just solved the problem! :D I still have some difficulties with another problem regarding lebesgue measure, I don't know if you could help me out a little bit

Comment: Yes, "Cauchy-Schwarz-Bunyakowsky" is the answer to many questions. :) Well, wouldn't hurt to post another question on this site... :)

Comment: I already posted it! I'll link it to you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414150/help-with-the-following-lebesgue-measure-problem?noredirect=1#comment9234992_4414150 even a little hint would be helpful